# is there something equivalent to "cudaMemcpy" from device global memory to host global memory that I can call within a device function?

Tags: cuda

cudaMemcpy in a device only supports device-to-device. I need to copy from device global to host global memory ( doesn't matter sync or async, although async is preferable ).

I would really appreciate your help!

Comment: Have you tried providing to the API function call a pointer to pinned memory obtained via cudaHostRegister and cudaHostGetDevicePointer - see https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-runtime-api/group__CUDART__MEMORY.html#group__CUDART__MEMORY_1gc00502b44e5f1bdc0b424487ebb08db0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is there something equivalent to `cudaMemcpy` from device global memory to host global memory that I can call within a device function?

No.

As pointed out in comments, your only choice here would be to use mapped or managed host memory which can be directly addressed in device code.